# How to make background-image non-stretchable?

Tags: css

In my project I've set background image with the following attributes:

```
body {
  background-image: url("/");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But when there are lots of elements on some page, this image stretching and enlarging to the bottom and, therefore, becomes ugly. How to do it non-stretchable? So that I can scroll down and that image would be constant.

Here's the [example](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/rOdMom) of the image stretching on CodePen. Below is the snippet:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=col-md-4>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        Some element
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please give a full example.

Comment: Maybe you want `background-size: contain`, maybe you want `background-attachment:fixed` or both? It's hard to tell, because you explicitly ask for the behaviour that you get by setting `background-size: cover`.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Check out how the image enlargement. I included example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want the background image to stretch then you should not set `background-size: cover` on the element. Setting the background size to cover would mean that the background image would be scaled (stretched) to fit the size of the container element.

> Here is what [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) says about `background-size: cover`:
>
> Scales the image as large as possible and maintains image aspect ratio (image doesn't get squished). The image "covers" the entire width or height of the container.

If you want the background image to remain constant even when scrolling down the page, you should add `background-attachment: fixed` to the element. This would keep the image in its place.

The `background-position: 50% 50%` in the below snippet is an optional setting which is just used to keep the background image positioned at the center-mid. This can be avoided if such a positioning is not required. By default the image would get positioned at top-left.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/850/420/nature/1");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
```

---

Note that stretching happens with `background-size: cover` only when the `background-attachment: fixed` setting is not applied (meaning, the image is not constant and gets stretched to fit container's full height/width) or when the image is smaller than the container. When it is larger than the container and `background-attachment: fixed` setting is applied, the image does not get stretched.

Another thing to note with `background-size: cover` is that when the image and the container have different sizes, [the image is clipped at the sides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). If it should be shrunk instead of  being clipped then `background-size: 100% 100%` could also be used.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/850/420/nature/1");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div{
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet......</div>
```

Comment: Great answer! But what do I do if the image is too large for the screen and I need it to fit in the width and the height of the whole screen?

Comment: You mean shrink to fit? Let me think a bit.

Comment: Exactly. When I go without `cover` attribute, It fails to fit the screen width.

Comment: Ok, that sounds a bit tricky because `cover` will always scale to fit and so will cause problems for smaller image whereas avoiding it won't shrink larger ones. Are you trying to write something like a template CSS which will work for images of any size?

Comment: Maybe you know some services that are able to proportionally resize an image?

Comment: No, I have the only one image and it's supposed to be on any page as background. However its resolution way greater than my screen resolution.

Comment: @BillyLogan: Hmm, if you have a single image which is always bigger than screen resolution then you can still set `cover`. The `background-attachment` will make it not stretch and always be constant. Can you try and ping me if it doesn't work?